# Is there any "idiom" or pattern in JS that'll let me pause execution while an animation runs?

Tags: javascript, animation, wait, continuations

I basically have this code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
  ShowCard(i);
}
```

Right now, ShowCard is just adding a DOM element, but I want it to have an animation that'll show this card flying from somewhere else (the shoe) into its final destination, and I want the second card to wait until the first one is done flying before it starts.

Is there any way to achieve this, without rewriting my whole code in "continuation passing" style?

I'm assuming the answer is no and i'll have to bit the bullet and do it, but thought i'd ask.

Thanks!
Daniel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no.

The only blocking APIs in JavaScript are the built in ones - `alert`, `confirm` and `prompt`.

Answer (score 2):

You can try jQuery's new [`deferred` API](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/using-deferreds-in-jquery/).

Comment: This looks interesting, but feels more complicated than just rewriting in CPS. I may be very wrong, though

Answer (score 1):

You could put in a global locking variable `inMotion` that indicates the second card can't move. Then in the code that is calling for the second card to move, you can check this boolean and if it's not time to move, use setTimeout or setInterval to continuously call your method until it is time to move it.

Comment: My problem is that i'm doing this inside a loop (I have "n" carts), so this gets tricky. But other than that... How is this different from just making a continuation and passing it as a parameter to the function that animates each card?

Comment: @Daniel Magliola - I can't really say that it's different because a case could be made either way. It's not strictly continuation, but it dove-tails easily into it.

Answer (score 0):

**Evil hack:** Instead of making your animations work using setTimeout and friends (functions that give away the control flow), make them work the dumb way using while loops, spin lock style. In pseudo code:

```
next_time = curr_time + delta;
while(get_time() < next_time){} //Do nothing
```

Comment: Yeah, I actually considered that :-)  Buy jQuery animating is sweet enough that i'd rather bite the bullet and rewrite in CPS, than animate manually.